# basic fact about p-group

Tags: group-theory

I'm studying Lang's undergraduate algebra. In the section of finite abelian groups, I have a question about $p$-group.

In the book, they define:

1. A $p$-group is a finite group whose order is a power of $p$.
2. If $A$ is an abelian group and $p$ a prime number, denote by $A(p)$ the subgroup of all elements $x \in A$ whose period is a power of $p$.

Then they remark: $A(p)$ is a $p$-group if it is finite.

I have difficulty to understand why it is so trivial. By definition, the order of $A(p)$ should have the form $p^r t$, since each element has period a power of $p$. But why the order of $A(p)$ must be a power of $p$?

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy's theorem, if a prime $q \not= p$ divides $\lvert A(p) \rvert$, $A(p)$ would contain an element of order $q$.

Comment: Thanks! But they never talk about Cauchy's theorem before and this is an elementary book, until this point, they only introduce very basic group concepts like coset, homomorphism, etc.

Comment: It's not a particularly difficult proof (depending on which proof you read).  You should be able to follow [the one on proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_Group_Theorem).  The part about a group acting on another group is the only part that may or may not have been discussed yet.  The proof comes from [this article](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/McKay59.pdf) which may or may not be more readable.

Comment: I really appreciate it! I think from your answer, this fact is not entirely trivial so it shouldn't be just mentioned in the book in that way. There was a gap in the book.

Comment: But you only need Cauchy's theorem for abelian groups for this question, which is easier than the general case. Provided that you know about quotient groups, it is an easy induction on the order of the group.